# Axon Send commands to other microservices

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I am using axon for CQRS, Saga pattern.Now I have a scenario where one microservice send a command to another microservice. Can we do that using Axon command bus processing.

Answer (score 4):

Axon provides `DistributedCommandBus` implementation of `CommandBus` which you'll need to set up for your microservices in order to have Axon routing commands to the correct Aggregate.

The 'out of the box' support in the framework for connecting different segments of a command bus is done either via JGroups or SpringCloud. It is also possible to have all this wired up using [AxonHub](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axonhub). Of course, you can always provide your implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, yes and no. You'll still have to have `DistributedCommandBus` configured in that micro service which means that you'll have to use Java for it. But you can still invoke your .NET code if you expose it (via REST API for example).